# urllib2.Request post equivalent in node.js

Tags: python, node.js, request, urllib2

I am trying to use the coins-e API with a node.js application, but I am having trouble with the authenticated POST requests. I have a request written in python here:

```
post_args['method'] = method        
post_args['nonce'] = nonce        
post_data = urllib.urlencode(post_args)
required_sign = hmac.new(PRIVATE_KEY, post_data, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
headers = {}
headers['key'] = PUBLIC_KEY
headers['sign'] = required_sign
url_request_object = urllib2.Request("%s/%s" % (BASE_API_URL,url_suffix),
                                 post_data,
                                 headers)    
response = urllib2.urlopen(url_request_object)    


try:
    response_content = response.read()
    response_json = json.loads(response_content)
    print response_json
finally:
    response.close()
```

and this is the node.js code I have written attempting to do the same thing:

```
var request = require('request');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var crypto = require('crypto');

var post_args = {};
post_args['nonce'] = nonce;
post_args['method'] = method;
var post_data = querystring.stringify(postdata);

var hasher = crypto.createHmac('sha512', PRIVATE_KEY);
hasher.update(post_data);
var required_sign = hasher.digest('hex');

var headers = {};

headers['key'] = PUBLIC_KEY;
headers['sign'] = required_sign;

var options = {
    uri: url,
    qs: post_data,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers
};

request(options, function(error, response, body){
    console.log(body);
});
```

Looking to see if someone can either tell me what the difference between the post made in python and the one made in node.js, or if someone can help me set up a post request for the coins-e API that works in node.js.

Here is a link to the coins-e API: https://www.coins-e.com/exchange/api/documentation/
The description for how to format the authenticated requests is about halfway down the page just before entry 6. Thanks for the help!

Comment: hey @TheDuckManKing, how did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

i don't have account there to test it but it looks like it should be

```
var post_data = querystring.stringify(post_args);
```